# Python Array with String Indices

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

Is it possible to use strings as indices in an array in python?

For example:

```
myArray = []
myArray["john"] = "johns value"
myArray["jeff"] = "jeffs value"
print myArray["john"]
```

Comment: what you are showing are __lists__, not arrays. Call me pedantic.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

What you want is called an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). In python these are called [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

> Dictionaries are sometimes found in other languages as “associative memories” or “associative arrays”. Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, **dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type**; strings and numbers can always be keys.

```
myDict = {}
myDict["john"] = "johns value"
myDict["jeff"] = "jeffs value"
```

Alternative way to create the above dict:

```
myDict = {"john": "johns value", "jeff": "jeffs value"}
```

Accessing values:

```
print(myDict["jeff"]) # => "jeffs value"
```

Getting the keys (in Python v2):

```
print(myDict.keys()) # => ["john", "jeff"]
```

In Python 3, you'll get a `dict_keys`, which is a view and a bit more efficient (see [views docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) and [PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) for details).

```
print(myDict.keys()) # => dict_keys(['john', 'jeff'])
```

---

If you want to learn about python dictionary internals, I recommend this ~25 min video presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68. It's called the "The Mighty Dictionary".

Comment: Great example. Something always good to know about Dictionaries in Python is that, as [The MYYN](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89391/the-myyn) said, the key must be of an immutable type. If you ever need to categorise values with "multiple" keys, you have to use the Tuple type in Python.

Comment: Technically the key [has to be _hashable_ ](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), not necessarily immutable, although the value returned by the `hash` function should not change as long as the object is used as a dictionary key. If it does, be prepared for your program to crash or misbehave in bizarre ways.

Comment: Above The Mighty Dictionary url is not working, find at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68

Answer (score 5):

Even better, try an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (assuming you want something like a list).  Closer to a list than a regular dict since the keys have an order just like list elements have an order.  With a regular dict, the keys have an arbitrary order.

Note that this is available in Python 3 and 2.7.  If you want to use with an earlier version of Python you can find installable modules to do that.

Comment: Note that needing an OrderedDict is much less common than needing a dict.

Comment: @MikeGraham, true, but an ordered dict will behave more like a list which is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answers completely miss the point of constructing an array of dicts, indexed with a key, e.g.,

Bands with concerts by band name:

```
concerts = []

concerts['bandname1'] = {"venue": city stadium, "State": state name, "Date": date value, "Time": event time }

concerts['bandname2'] = {"venue": different city stadium, "State": another state name, "Date": some other date value, "Time": event time }
```

It can't be done. Python will not allow a string index, only an integer or a slice.