# What is this syntax in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

if there is a syntax like this in python 
what exactly is it declaring defining?

I tried looking in in the python website did not seen anything like this

`children = cell["CHILDREN"]`

Answer (score 2):

It is accessing the item in dictionary `cell` with key `"CHILDREN"` and assigning it to the variable `children`.

More useful references:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm
- http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html
- http://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php

Answer (score 1):

That line refers to dictionaries, also known as associative arrays. The line of code in question assigns the value in the dictionary that associates to the key `CHILDREN` to the variable `children`.

Read more about this in a [great related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765543/756329).

Comment: Wouldn't the syntax in the question throw something akin to Ruby's `Dynamic Constant Assignment` exception? This is moving a constant's memory location elsewhere, which is typically a no-no.

Comment: @CollinGraves Good question and I'm not sure. Maybe you should ask it!

Comment: I haven't used ruby , not sure what a dynamic constant is , but looking at the code right now , seems like a dictionary reference

Answer (score 0):

cell is a dictionary.  A dictionary is an unordered set of key: value pairs.  The element cell["CHILDREN"] is retrieved and stored in the variable children. More on dictionaries here:

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
- https://pythonspot.com/python-dictionaries/