# How to print out json objects without using [0]?

Tags: python, json

So I have been playing around with JSONand been trying to print out but without any luck. Basically what JSONI am trying to print out is the *cityplace* as you will see here:

```
{
  'id': '5235246c-ac21a7-151128-8cd9-512512',
  'type': 'Hello world',
  'metadata': {
    'invite_text': "A very cool text here!!",
    'cityplace': [
      {
        'display_text': 'Stackoverflow City',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have done for code is that I made a loop that prints out by calling the name `test_print` which gives me the JSON object that I printed out.

What I did try was

```
print(test_print['metadata']['cityplace']['display_text'])
```

unfortunately this give me error

> ```
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ```

So what I needed to do is:

```
print(test_print['metadata']['cityplace'][0]['display_text'])
```

and now my question is: Is it possible to print out without needing to add `[0]` because it might not always be `0` in the future?

Comment: `print(test_print['metadata']['cityplace'][0]['display_text'])` ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. That's a list, if you want to print out the first item you need to use `[0]`, if you want to print every item you can iterate through with a loop

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, I did printed out saying that it worked but my question is, if its possible to make it without adding the [0] ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can I make it loop in that case? I don't know how to check how long the list is? Or..?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @roganjosh Oh okey! There we have it, then I assume I need to make it another way.

Comment: Why do you need to check how long it is? Just do `for item in test_print['metadata']['cityplace']: print(item['display_text'])`.

Comment: I didn't thought about it! Well I solved it now by making the for loop and seems to work as I wanted to! :D thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cityplace` is a list. Use Index.

**Ex:**

```
test_print = {
  'id': '5235246c-ac21a7-151128-8cd9-512512',
  'type': 'Hello world',
  'metadata': {
    'invite_text': "A very cool text here!!",
    'cityplace': [
      {
        'display_text': 'Stackoverflow City',
      }
    ]
  }
}

print(test_print['metadata']['cityplace'][0]['display_text'])
```

Or iterate it.

**Ex:**

```
for i in test_print['metadata']['cityplace']:
    print(i["display_text"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You `cityplace` is not a JSON. It is a list containing only one JSON. So, you have to pick the JSON from it, which is, of course, `[0]`. If the list is gonna have more elements in the future, you will need to iterate

```
 texts = [city['display_text'] for city in test_print['metadata']['cityplace']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using indexed array , the only way to access the array values is using index of the array (and will be always 0 - doesn't change in future).

You can use associative array, in order to access the access key and its value.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765533/python-array-with-string-indices) may help you in creating associative array.